# How to get JSON records values for column work_status and text1 using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below was used to display JSON records in React.js and it's working fine, as I can display data id and name.

How do I also get/display values for **work_status (eg status 1, status 3, status 9)** and **text1 (Eg. Ann, Tony, John)**?

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
    
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[
        {
          "id": "2788621216",
          "name": "Item 1",
          "column_values": [
            {
              "id": "work_status",
              "value": "\"status1\""
            },
            {
              "id": "text1",
              "value": "\"Ann\""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2757366595",
          "name": "item 2",
          "column_values": [
            {
              "id": "work_status",
              "value": "\"status 3\""
            },
            {
              "id": "text1",
              "value": "\"Tony\""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2758432275",
          "name": "Item 3",
          "column_values": [
            {
              "id": "work_status",
              "value": "\"status 9\""
            },
            {
              "id": "text1",
              "value": "\"John\""
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    };
  }
     
  componentDidMount() {}
    
  render() {
    const { } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>     
        {this.state.data.map(b => (
          <div key={b.id} className=''>
            <div class="card-body">
              <b>BId:</b> {b.id}
              <br />
              <b>Name:</b> {b.name}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
export default App;
```

Comment: The same way you map over the data, do another search through `b. column_values`, find the value with the correct type (`c.id === 'work_status'`) and then just display the value as you normally would `<b>Status:</b> {c.value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have fixed-position of values you can use this

[Look At this JSFieddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tc5Ls7ou/5/)

```
<div>
      {this.state.data.map((b, i) => (
        <div key={b.i}>
          <div class="card-body">
            <b>BId:</b> {b.id}
            <br />
            <b>Name:</b> {b.name}
          </div>

          <div class="work-status">
            <h4>Work status</h4>
            <p> {b.column_values[0].value.replace(/"/g, "")} </p>
          </div>

          <div class="text-1">
            {/* text */}
            <h4> Text</h4>
            <p> {b.column_values[1].id} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working now @Ganesh MB, please is there anyway to remove the double quotes that surrounds the displayed values eg **"status1"** and others

Comment: @NancyMoore You can remove double quotes by using this regex ```.replace(/"/g, "")```.  I updated codes check it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try creating an object with the all relevant properties like below

```
let output = data.map(x => {
    let item = {};
  
  item["id"] = x.id;
  item["name"] = x.name;
  
  x.column_values.forEach(y => {
    item[y.id] = y.value;
  
  })
  
  return item;
});
```

and map through this (all your required fields will be available on the object)